# Who deleted the answer

Tags: support, deleted-answers

A [deleted answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29741/what-is-meant-by-the-974-worlds-that-were-created-and-destroyed/60802#60802) says "deleted 20 mins ago" at the bottom.

Deleted by whom? Deleted by [Community](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/-1)? Deleted by User?

Comment: This behaviour isn't unique to Judaism.SE, no, but considering that your example comes from here, it's most beneficial to answer your question here on Meta.Judaism.SE where other high-rep users can benefit from it in case they have the same question.

Answer (score 3):

The answer was deleted from the Low Quality review queue: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/18716.

Off the top of my head, I don't believe we have other deletion causes right now that'd avoid listing the user(s) involved, so review-queue-driven deletion is a safe bet when you see something like this.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Most commonly, that the answer was removed due to spam/offensive flags.

Answer (score 3):

As Anna [said](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3603/472), a post that says "deleted" without saying by whom was deleted from the low-quality review queue.  This queue allows users without a delete vote to recommend deletion; six such votes delete the post.  I imagine that Stack Exchange chose not to list the six voters because it would lead to confusion -- by definition, none of those people have the "vote to delete" privilege, so seeing their names there could seem odd.  It's a pity that it doesn't instead say "deleted from review".

As far as I know this is the only unattributed deletion.  A post deleted by spam or offensive flags will say "deleted by Community", one deleted by the owner will say "deleted by owner", and one deleted by users with the privilege will say "deleted by (names)".  If a question is deleted answers will also say "deleted" without attribution, but in that case the *question* deletion will be attributed, so you can see it there.